# AMD Ryzen Laptop ignores max CPU frequency set by tlp

Tags: power-management, battery, amd-processor, amd-ryzen

This is on Kubuntu 22.04 LTS.

To extend battery life of an Ryzen 9 5900HX laptop, I installed the `tlp` service and configured it in /etc/tlp.conf as follows (all configurations not mentioned here are unchanged):

```
CPU_SCALING_GOVERNOR_ON_AC=ondemand
CPU_SCALING_GOVERNOR_ON_BAT=conservative
CPU_SCALING_MAX_FREQ_ON_AC=4680000
CPU_SCALING_MAX_FREQ_ON_BAT=1800000
```

The frequencies are set correctly, as can be seen from: `cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq`

```
1800000
1800000
1800000
1800000
1800000
1800000
1800000
1800000
1800000
1800000
1800000
1800000
1800000
1800000
1800000
1800000
```

Unfortunately, the CPU doesn't respect those frequencies, as verified via: `grep MHz /proc/cpuinfo`

It seems, that the max frequency is somewhat respected, when all cores are busy, like in this result:

```
cpu MHz         : 2180.130
cpu MHz         : 2179.499
cpu MHz         : 2178.976
cpu MHz         : 2176.884
cpu MHz         : 2176.504
cpu MHz         : 2175.368
cpu MHz         : 2174.998
cpu MHz         : 2173.944
cpu MHz         : 2173.575
cpu MHz         : 2172.539
cpu MHz         : 2172.196
cpu MHz         : 2171.268
cpu MHz         : 2170.889
cpu MHz         : 2169.865
cpu MHz         : 2169.522
cpu MHz         : 2168.473
```

However, when only a few cores are used, the picture is actually like this:

```
cpu MHz         : 2967.377
cpu MHz         : 400.000
cpu MHz         : 400.000
cpu MHz         : 400.000
cpu MHz         : 3004.301
cpu MHz         : 400.000
cpu MHz         : 1710.000
cpu MHz         : 2863.831
cpu MHz         : 400.000
cpu MHz         : 400.000
cpu MHz         : 400.000
cpu MHz         : 400.000
cpu MHz         : 1440.000
cpu MHz         : 4029.349
cpu MHz         : 400.000
cpu MHz         : 400.000
```

So it seems to me, that the power, that would be available for "all cores at 1800 MHz" is redistributed to the actually actives cores, allowing three of them to run at around 3000 MHz and one even at 4000 MHz.

**I don't want that power shift!** The main reason is, that I tend to have quite a few browser tabs open, and (too) many modern websites have some background tasks, that keep Firefox busy, so that one or two cores are always fully loaded. But I don't want them to jump to turbo frequencies and drain my battery unnecessarily. So I want all cores to stay below the selected frequency.

Here is a sample output from `cpupower frequency-info`

```
analyzing CPU 0:
  driver: amd-pstate
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 0
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 0
  maximum transition latency: 131 us
  hardware limits: 400 MHz - 4.68 GHz
  available cpufreq governors: conservative ondemand userspace powersave performance schedutil
  current policy: frequency should be within 400 MHz and 1.80 GHz.
                  The governor "conservative" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
  current CPU frequency: Unable to call hardware
  current CPU frequency: 3.09 GHz (asserted by call to kernel)
  boost state support:
    Supported: yes
    Active: yes
    Boost States: 0
    Total States: 3
    Pstate-P0:  3300MHz
    Pstate-P1:  1300MHz
    Pstate-P2:  1200MHz
```

It is clearly shown, that the policy is between 400 MHz and 1.80 GHz, but the actual frequency is 3.09 GHz and Pstate-P0 is even 3.3 GHz.

On another answer, it was suggested to use `cpupower frequency-set --max 1800000`, but that didn't have any effect, either.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably related to a kernel bug, that after a sleep, the maximum frequencies are no longer respected by the driver:

https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=215938

However, a system reboot did NOT change the situation for me:

```
cpu MHz         : 400.000
cpu MHz         : 400.000
cpu MHz         : 400.000
cpu MHz         : 400.000
cpu MHz         : 3268.709
cpu MHz         : 400.000
cpu MHz         : 2614.703
cpu MHz         : 400.000
cpu MHz         : 2789.985
cpu MHz         : 2847.641
cpu MHz         : 400.000
cpu MHz         : 400.000
cpu MHz         : 400.000
cpu MHz         : 400.000
cpu MHz         : 400.000
cpu MHz         : 400.000
```

Well, after waiting few minutes after a reboot, the situation actually DID correct:

```
cpu MHz         : 400.000
cpu MHz         : 400.000
cpu MHz         : 400.000
cpu MHz         : 1480.040
cpu MHz         : 400.000
cpu MHz         : 400.000
cpu MHz         : 1479.909
cpu MHz         : 400.000
cpu MHz         : 400.000
cpu MHz         : 400.000
cpu MHz         : 400.000
cpu MHz         : 400.000
cpu MHz         : 400.000
cpu MHz         : 400.000
cpu MHz         : 1773.580
cpu MHz         : 400.000
```

So most likely this is related to the mentioned kernel bug and goes away, when the scaling error bug is backported into the 22.04 LTS kernel. And yes, I hope it is backported, because running on too high frequencies and thus draining the battery ends up being a Denial Of Service!